# Updating TXTRecordDictionary doesn't always notify monitoring services

Tags: ios, bonjour, nsnetservice

I'm using bonjour to find other devices. Each device uses `TXTRecordData` to share its name:

```
NSDictionary* dictionary = @{ @"name": @"Goose" };
[service setTXTRecordData:[NSNetService dataFromTXTRecordDictionary:dictionary]];
```

Each device listens for changes:

```
- (void) netService:(NSNetService *)sender didUpdateTXTRecordData:(NSData *)data
{
    ...
}
```

About 80% of the time it works - `didUpdateTXTRecordData` is called when a name is changed.

Sometimes the other devices are never notified.

I've checked and `setTXTRecordData` returns `YES` when the data is lost.

How can I make sure updates to the TXTRecordData makes it to other devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone posted [a gist demonstrating what is possibly the above bug](https://gist.github.com/n-b/2214443).

For you Apple people out there, the gist says the relevant rdar is rdar://11018654